# How to define a class function and print only numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working a class call MarbleBoard and my code is below :

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, balls):
        self.balls=balls
        print (self.balls)

board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5))
```

The reasult I got is:

```
(3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 0, 8, 2, 5)
```

But I want to get the result below

```
board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5)) 
board 
3 6 7 4 1 0 8 2 5
```

Comment: The function needs to be indented to make it part of the class.

Comment: change to `print(" ".join(self.balls))`

Comment: Or `print(*self.balls)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are workin with a class, you can use the `__repr__` method to compute the "oficial" string reputation of an object:

```
class MarblesBoard():
    def __init__(self, balls):
        self.balls = balls

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(str(i) for i in self.balls)
```

Now, when you call the `board` variable you get this output:

```
board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5))
board
3 6 7 4 1 0 8 2 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than printing in the `__init__` method, you should define a `__repr__` method for your class.

For example:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return ' '.join([str(ball) for ball in self.balls])
```

Then you can do:

```
board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5)) 
print(board)
3 6 7 4 1 0 8 2 5
```